# R: How to combine two char vectors so that result looks like char1 [char2]

Tags: r

I am, trying to combine two char vectors char1 & char2, so that the final result is a string with one char within Square brackets char1[char2] and so on. The simplest function that strikes is paste, but it does not allow me to insert one char withn Square brackets. is there anyway, that someone has figured out to generate the following result in the eg. below ?

```
x <- c(Char1, Char2, Char3)
y <- c(Char4, Char5, Char6)
Expected output...
(Char1[Char4], Char2[Char5], Char3[Char6])
```

Any suggestions and help is greaty appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `sprintf`:

```
> x <- c("Char1", "Char2", "Char3")
> y <- c("Char4", "Char5", "Char6")
> sprintf("%s[%s]", x, y)
[1] "Char1[Char4]" "Char2[Char5]" "Char3[Char6]"
```

If you want a single string, then maybe combine this with `paste` and `collapse`.

Or maybe you're after something like:

```
> sprintf("(%s)", paste(x, "[", y, "]", sep = "", collapse = ", "))
[1] "(Char1[Char4], Char2[Char5], Char3[Char6])"
```

Comment: Hi ananda, thank you for reply.  Is there a way to insert comma between the combined strings.and unquote them. The output I am expecting should be in the following format,  because this is inturn an input to another function. `(Char1[Char4], Char2[Char5], Char3[Char6])`

Comment: @user5249203, it sounds like you're going down a slippery slope. What exactly are you trying to do? You can look into `expression`, `noquote`, and `eval` for some places to start, but without knowing what function you plan to use this with, I'm not sure I'd be able to make a better suggestion.

Comment: Hi Ananda, The goal is to create an NCBI search query to use with `entrez_search(db = "pubmed", term = query, retmax = 20)`

Comment: Oops, Sorry I did not check your edited answer. that work, except for that I need the " to be removed in the output. I used `noquote` to do that. Thank you Ananda

Comment: The double quotes seem like they are there but that is just the display in the console. Internally the data is being saved without it. When you save it to ".txt" or ".csv" it will go away. Try `cat("abc")` to see the "real" output.